# Android NFC Intent for notification instead of activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications, nfc

Is there a way to make a nfc tag show a notification instead of opening the actual activity?

I need my app to not show up when it is placed on a nfc tag, but instead show a notification. I have googled around for a way, but not found anything, thus not much code.

I currently have my app set up to open the main activity when it discovers an Ndef tag.

Foreground dispatcher is enabled and works, I just need to know a way to show a notification instead of the actual app activity.

MainActivity onCreate:

```
IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter( NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED );
try {
    ndef.addDataType( "*/*" );
}
catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "fail", e );
}

nfcFilters = new IntentFilter[] { ndef, };
nfcTechList = new String[][] {
        new String[] { NfcA.class.getName() },
        new String[] { NfcB.class.getName() },
        new String[] { NfcV.class.getName() },
        new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() },
        new String[] { Ndef.class.getName() },
        new String[] { NdefFormatable.class.getName() },
        new String[] { MifareClassic.class.getName() },
        new String[] { MifareUltralight.class.getName() },
        new String[] { IsoDep.class.getName() },
        new String[] { NfcBarcode.class.getName() },
    };
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

An app called Trigger does what I want. When you set a task and close the app, then place the app over the nfc tag,  the app does not pop up and shows a notification instead.

Would also be useful to know if I can separate them so it shows a notification when the app is closed, but if it's running it should do something in the

---

EDIT:

Alright, I found a way to do all of this. The way I did it is to have another Activity which will listen to Ndef discovery. Now, to make the application open the new Activity, I had to add a record with a custom mime type (TNF_MIME_MEDIA) with a mime type of my app package. I also needed an Application Record as the last record in the NFC tag.

Now the app will start up with the new Activity I created.
Inside this Activity's onCreate method, I simply created the notification and then ran finish().

I didn't do this before because I assumed that doing it this way would show the activity, show the notification, then immediately close it (closing any apps that was previously opened).
This was not the case though, so it works perfectly.

Can someone tell me if this is a good or bad way to solve it.

Comment: If you have foreground dispatch enabled, then you have an activity in the foreground, and you do not need a `Notification`. Just update the UI of your existing activity.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I phrased it incorrectly. I want a botification to show up instead of the activity whwn I place my phone on the nfc tag and keep the activity closed. Normally, the activity gets the intent and opens it up, but I need it to stay closed and only show a notification.

Comment: There are two tag dispatch systems. The foreground dispatch system and the tag intent dispatch system. Both of these systems require an activity to catch the tag, so i think it's a good way to solve your problem. As far as i know there is no such thing as a background service to catch a tag. Note that this is possible with HCE.